# How to print leading whitespace with $(info)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to print indented output with `$(info ...)`

Make ignores whitespace after `info`, so the following doesn't work:

```
$(info  There is a space and then a tab before this text)
```

It will print:

```
There is a space and then a tab before this text
```

So right now I'm doing this (which isn't exactly what I want, but close enough):

```
$(info -    Here there is a space, a dash, and then a tab)
```

It will print:

```
-   Here there is a space, a dash, and then a tab
```

Is it possible to print the following?:

```
    Is it possible to print me?
```

I know I can `echo(1)`, but I've seen considerable performance loss by doing that, so I'd prefer to use `$(info)`, even if I have to print a leading dash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put something that expands as the empty string on front of your spaces:

```
NULL :=
$(info $(NULL)          X)
```

The `$(NULL)` token plays the role of delimiter between `info` and the string parameter.

Instead of `NULL` you could even use a macro that would expand as the specified number of spaces. It would play the role of the `NULL` variable in the previous example, plus add the requested number of spaces.

```
$ cat Makefile
info-spaces = $(subst -, ,$(subst $(eval) ,,$(wordlist 1,$(1),\
  $(foreach n,0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9,- - - - - - - - - -))))

.PHONY: all

N ?= 0

all:
    $(info 0123456789)
    $(info $(call info-spaces,$(N))X)
    @:

$ make
0123456789
X
$ make N=10
0123456789
          X
$ make N=5
0123456789
     X
```

> Note: you can add up to 100 spaces, no more. Modify the `foreach` call to increase or reduce this maximum.

Explanations:

- The `$(foreach ...)` call creates a list of 100 words, all equal to `-`.
- `$(wordlist ...)` returns the `N` first words where `N` is the parameter passed to the `info-spaces` macro (If `N`=0 it returns the empty string, and if `N`>100 it returns 100 words).
- `$(subst $(eval) ,,...)` removes the spaces from the list of words, leaving one single word with `min(N,100)` times the `-` character. Here `$(eval)` does absolutely nothing, it's just a way to use a space as first parameter of `subst`. It is the same as `$(NULL)` in the first solution. We could probably use something else as long as it expands to the empty string.
- Finally, the outermost `subst` substitutes each `-` character by one space and returns a string of `min(N,100)` spaces.

> Note: We could also use `$(shell printf '%$(1)s' "")` instead of this complicated stuff but if you have performance issues spawning a new shell for each `info` call is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If `$(info)`'s text parameter is empty it will output nothing and
expand to nothing, making it usable as a zero-width character, e.g.

```
$(info $(info)   indented text)
\t  := $(info)  $(info)
```

which outputs    `indented text` and defines `\t` as a tab character.